# cannot load linear layout from main.xml in a dyanimic layout

Tags: android

I am trying to make dynamic layout  in which there is a scroll view.
In the scroll view , I am adding vertical linear layout which references main.xml.
The code stops as soon , I try to add the layout referencing main.xml.

```
 ScrollView scroll;
    EditText search;
    Button checkin;
        LinearLayout vt;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            scroll=new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
            vt=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llv);///referencing linear layout located in main.xml.This is where problem the  is occurring.
            //vt.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            scroll.addView(vt);
            this.setContentView(scroll);
        }
```

main.xml ( where R.id.llv is located )

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
         <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

before:

```
  vt=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llv);
```

Comment: You are getting the question wrong.
I am trying to add linear layout from main.xml in a dyanimic layout.

Comment: @ShoaibKhan you need to inflate your xml first.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
view row  = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, null);
LinearLayout layout=row.findViewById(R.id.YourLayout);
```

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
View row  = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, null);
View vt= row.findViewById(R.id.llv);
scroll=new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
scroll.addView(vt);
this.setContentView(scroll);

This is what I m doing.But still force close

Answer (score 0):

Check this to create Linear Layout Dynamically.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/